# how to select entity with contition one to many entity more than zero

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I got entity Mission, a missions got Collect entity with oneToMany,
I want to select the missions which got less than the maxParticipant setted in mission, I try something but count on oneToMany relation do not exist

```
public function getMissionGroupByCities()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
        ->select('COUNT(m) as count_project, m_city.id as id, IDENTITY(m_city.nameLibelle) as libelle, m_city.latitude, m_city.longitude')
        ->leftJoin('m.project', 'm_project')
        ->leftJoin('m.city', 'm_city')
        ->groupBy('m.city')
        ->where('m_project.state IN (2,3,4)')
        ->andWhere('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() < m_project.dateEnd')
        ->andWhere('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() < m.dateBegin')
        ->andWhere('count(m.collects) < m.maxParticipant');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 346 near 'collects) <
>   m.maxParticipant': Error: Invalid PathExpression.
>   StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.

how can I do the last test ? : andWhere('count(m.collects) < m.maxParticipant');

Answer (score 1):

Try using having clausole:

```
    ->having('count(m.collects) < m.maxParticipant');
```

Hope this help

Comment: No, col 365 near 'collects) < ': Error: Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected.

Comment: and with `count(m.collects.id)` ?